# Using endorsements in Hyperledger Fabric to design a process

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would really like to understand how endorsments work in Hyperledger Fabric in order to help me in designing a solution to a problem.

let's assume I am an endorser and a transaction proposal has just arrived. I would randomly select a participant within my organization, use its identity to perform the validations, checking for replay attacks etc then sign an endorsement with that participant's private key. Assuming I used an admin's credentials, the admin(person) may not be aware that I used its identities to validate and endorse a transaction proposal. Is this example correct?

Initial discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675326/using-endorsements-in-hyperledger-composer-to-design-a-process?noredirect=1#comment82341375_47675326) makes me feel like the more I look into it, the more confused I become. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Just to start with, the endorser is the peer that capable to handle incoming invocation, maintain and run the chaincode. The flow works as following, support you have a client (C) and the endorsing peer (P), which runs a chaincode (CC).

1. Client forms transaction proposal request which includes parameters for chaincode invocation.
2. In order to get an endorsement for this proposal he sends it the endorsing peer.
3. Endorsing peer opens a transaction proposal and forwards requests to the required chaincode along the way it passes all parameters.
4. Chaincode get invoked which produces a RWset (set of keys and values read of changed during the invocation)
5. Peer collects RWset and forms proposal response and signs it
6. Client gets the proposal response, signs it as well and send it to the ordering service
7. Ordering service collects proposal responses and cuts the block which got distributed to the peers in the network.
8. Upon arrival peers opens a block and validates all transactions, one of the validation is to check whenever transaction conforms the endorsement policy, where basically it checks whenever transaction has enough signatures which satisfies the policy.

Back to your question, please note that at each step everyone uses its own key and certificate to sign, no one randomly selects participants to use they identities for signatures or whatever else.

PS. Note that process above a bit simplified and lack a lot of technical details.

PPS. There is a new course on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ibm-blockchain-essentials-for-developers) which covers pretty well many technical aspects of Hyperledger Fabric architecture and the interaction between different components, I would urge you to consider taking this course.

Comment: Thanks for your simplified description which makes sense to me. I will look into taking the course. If we work with this example, I reckon we will have 3 signatures each at steps 1, 5 and 6. 1 and 6 for client while 5 for endorser. This makes sense. What confuses me is when some descriptions begin mentioning members e.g.[here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1251) and [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/arch-deep-dive.html?highlight=endorsement#endorsement-policies). It then appears as if also members/admin in the endorsing peers can sign.